# Finding poles by inspection

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, integrated-circuit, frequency

I have a question regarding finding poles by inspection. The technique that I know is

- Find the resistance R tied from the node to AC ground.
- Find the capacitance C tied from the node to AC ground.

The pole can then be approximated as 1/RC.

Now, with that mind, consider the following circuit:
[image]

Consider the input pole (gate of M1). **The capacitance tied to AC ground is C1 and the input impedance of M1 is extremely large. Does that mean that the 1/RC pole is extremely low?** I see most books usually place an additional external resistor at the gate of M1 to calculate the pole, they don't take into account the input gate impedance of M1, why?

Thanks.

Comment: If the impedance of C1 is much less than the impedance of the gate-substrate semiconducting capacitor Vout will be always be Vdd.

Comment: What supplies Vin? What is its source impedance? Factor that into your question.

Comment: @BrianDrummond it is probably an AC source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The capacitance tied to AC ground is C1 and the input impedance of M1
> is extremely large. Does that mean that the 1/RC pole is extremely
> low?*

The input source impedance will define the resistance that is in-effect, in parallel with gate source capacitance. For a voltage source (such as \$V_{IN}\$ shown in the question), that is usually zero or very small for a practical source.

Comment: 'The input source impedance will define the resistance that is in-effect, in parallel with gate source capacitance. For a voltage source that is usually zero or very small for a practical source.' I only see 2 capacitors in parallel connected to an AC source.

Comment: @HelenaWells what two capacitors do you see? Additional question on source theory: what is the output impedance of a voltage source?

Comment: I see C1 and the gate-substrate which is in fact a MOS capacitor.( conductive-semiconductive plates seperated by insulating layer).

Comment: C1 is representing the gate source capacitance. There is only one capacitance. Theoretically there is another but you didn't spot that.

Comment: Yes but then it is not equivalent because we have 1 capacitor in parallel with something else, while we should have only 1 capacitor

Comment: @HelenaWells for the sake of this question, the dominant capacitance is \$C_{GS}\$. If you want to point out the slight error on the OP's part in omitting another capacitor then please go-ahead.

Comment: Amazing. Completely forgot about the input source impedance. Thanks very much! That would explain why most books put a resistance at the gate to model the previous stage or source impedance.